# How to name an attribute in a class with a reserved name

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have a simple problem, I am deserializing a Json, and I need my class attributes name to be exactly the same than on the original JSON. My problem is that one of the attribute must be named :"explicit" which is reserved... How can I solve this ?

```
    public Int32 page { get; set; }
    public Int32 limit { get; set; }
    public Boolean explicit {get;set;} // problem here explicit is reserved by the language
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prefix it with an @ sign

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
public Boolean @explicit {get;set;}
```